# Reduction Technique to consider Reduced Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a bit general question about a proof /reduction technique in algebraic geometry which encountered to me quite often:

Sometimes if one has a morphism $f:X \to Y$ of schemes one makes wlog the assumption that $X$ is reduced, so $X = X_{red}$. Why and im which cases it can be done? Some "famous" examples?

Comment: Unless you explain *where* this reduction is made, it is imposible to answer. That one can assume that X is reduced «wlog» is not an absoute thing: it really depends on what you are trying to prove. For some things you can assume it is reduced and for others you can't.

Comment: In general, if you want to show a purely topological property (e.g. irreducible, connected, surjective morphism, ...), you can wlog assume that your scheme is reduced.

Comment: Or if you want to show that a scheme is affine, you can assume that it is reduced.

Comment: @Moos: Your second comment isn't clear to me: If I want to show that a scheme is affine, why I can assume that it is reduced?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is usually when you have a closed *subset* $T$ of another scheme $X$ and want to give it a scheme structure. There are many possible structures one may take, but there is a unique choice which is reduced. Meaning, there is a unique reduced closed subscheme $Z \subset X$ whose underlying topological space is equal to that of $T$. You can look here at [[Stacks, tag 01IZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IZ)] for more information on this, including a universal property.

Comment: So it can be understood as "taking a canonical choice" for scheme structure for a fixed closed subset to work with it, so especially working with it's useful properties? But ***when*** it can be done? Or for which kinds of proof statements this reduction can be done wlog?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying "without loss of generality," because certainly you lose some generality here by choosing a specific structure. Instead, how I see it is that often one will encounter an object which is a closed subset of the topological space of a scheme and want to define it as a closed subscheme. One will then *define* this specific object to be this closed subset -with- this closed subscheme structure. Does that make sense?

Comment: I do not see how this answer adresses the question.